# openGL Translating pixel brightness to colormap texture produces incorrect result

Tags: opengl, textures, color-mapping

See gif switching between RGB and colormap:

[image]

**The problem is that the two images are different.**

I am drawing dots that are RGB white (1.0,1.0,1.0). The alpha channel controls pixel brightness, which creates the dot blur. That's what you see as the brighter image. Then I have a 2-pixel texture of black and white (0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0) (1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0) and in a fragment shader I do:

```
#version 330

precision highp float;

uniform sampler2D originalColor;
uniform sampler1D colorMap;
in vec2 uv;
out vec4 color;

void main()
{
  vec4 oldColor = texture(originalColor, uv);
  color = texture(colorMap, oldColor.a);
}
```

Very simply, take the fragment of the originalColor texture's alpha value of 0 to 1, and translate it to a new color with colorMap texture of  black to white. **There should be no difference between the two images! Or... at least, that's my goal.**

Here's my setup for the colormap texture

```
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
  glGenTextures(1, &colormap_texture_id); // get texture id
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, colormap_texture_id);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE); // required: stop texture wrapping
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); // required: scale texture with linear sampling
  glTexImage1D(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, colormapColors.size(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, colormapColors.data()); // setup memory
```

Render loop:

```
  GLuint textures[] = { textureIDs[currentTexture], colormap_texture_id };
  glBindTextures(0, 2, textures);

  colormapShader->use();
  colormapShader->setUniform("originalColor", 0);
  colormapShader->setUniform("colorMap", 1);
  renderFullScreenQuad(colormapShader, "position", "texCoord");
```

I am using a 1D texture as a colormap because it seems that's the only way to potentially have a 1000 to 2000 indexes of colormap values stored in the GPU memory. If there's a better way, let me know. I assume the problem is that the math for interpolating between two pixels is not right for my purposes.

**What should I do to get my expected results?**

To make sure there's no shenanigans I tried to following shader code:

```
color = texture(colorMap, oldColor.a); //incorrect results
color = texture(colorMap, (oldColor.r + oldColor.g + oldColor.b)/3); //incorrect
color = texture(colorMap, (oldColor.r + oldColor.g + oldColor.b + oldColor.a)/4); //incorrect
color = vec4(oldColor.a); //incorrect
color = oldColor; // CORRECT... obviously...
```

Comment: Your image link gives me a "Not Found" page

Comment: Is the colormap continuous (e.g. a gradient)?  If not, `GL_LINEAR` does not make sense.

Comment: the colormap is 2 pixels, not sure how "continuous" that is. image link fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to be more accurate, you'd need to change:

```
color = texture(colorMap, oldColor.a);
```

to

```
color = texture(colorMap, oldColor.a * 0.5 + 0.25);
```

Or more generally

```
color = texture(colorMap, oldColor.a * (1.0 - (1.0 / texWidth)) + (0.5 / texWidth));
```

Normally, you wouldn't notice the error, it's just because texWidth is so tiny that the difference is significant.

The reason for this is because the texture is only going to start linear filtering from black to white after you pass the centre of the first texel (at 0.25 in your 2 texel wide texture). The interpolation is complete once you pass the centre of the last texel (at 0.75).

If you had a 1024 texture like you mention you plan to end up with then interpolation starts at 0.000488 and I doubt you'd notice the error.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! It looks like I still have a problem where the overall brightness is different, but at least it's just a brightness problem now, not an interpolation problem. Increasing the pixel brightness arbitrarily solves this. Will have to investigate further.

Comment: f*** hmm... actually the problem is still not being fixed by changing the brightnesss, the problem must exist elsewhere. I have one idea of what it could be, will get back to this when I can. (though this answer gets me closer to the desired results)

Comment: It's possible that unless you've been careful, your alpha channel might not contain what you think it contains. If you render a texel with 0.5 alpha with a standard alpha blend then the framebuffer will not contain 0.5, it'll contain 0.25. Probably the easiest fix would be to just use color = texture(colorMap, oldColor.r * 0.5 + 0.25);. Otherwise you need to carefully change your alpha blend function so that it accumulates correctly, which can be done but is a bit fiddly.

Comment: Yes you are right! I just fixed it! I came back to stack to let you know, and then read your comment describing the problem exactly. I basically just switched `olColor.a * etc.` to `oldColor.r * etc.` Essentially because I am drawing white, I can use any channel, just not alpha channel, because like you say the alpha channel isn't being stored like I thought. It's adjusting the RGB based on the alpha.